# How do I more efficiently get a list's index values for all its record highest numbers?

Tags: python

Say I have a first list:

```
list = [0, 1, 0, 4, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 12, 9, 32, 31, 19, 44, 3]
```

And a second list of all numbers n in the first list such that n = max(list[:n]), like so:

```
list_max = [0, 1, 4, 5, 12, 32, 44]
```

Say I wanted to get a list of the index positions of list_max in list, which should equal:

```
list_max_pos = [0, 1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 14]
```

I could do something like:

```
list_max_pos = []
m = len(list_max)
for n in range (0, m):
    list_max_pos.append(list.index(list_max[n]))
```

The issue is that if the original list is extremely long, i.e., millions of values long, this becomes very inefficient, since it starts the search from the beginning each time. To save time, I could start the search for the index of each new value where the index of the last value left off. That is to say, after 32 is found at position 11 in list, I could search for 44 starting from position 12 onward, rather than from 0 again.

How would I implement this?

Comment: If you have a consecutive duplicate max values, do you want them both in the list, which your problem statement implies?  Or was that unintentional?  E.g. `[0, 2, 7, 7, 1, 10]` - do you want `[0, 2, 7, 7, 10]` or just `[0, 2, 7, 10]`?

Comment: Also, I don't think the code you posted works.

Comment: Just sort the two lists, remembering the index positions of the elements and do a linear scan. This should be O(N * log N + M * log M).

Comment: @TomKarzes You're right, I messed up there. I'd want [0, 2, 7, 10].

Comment: In case you want to stick with your original implementation, `list.index()` takes an optional argument `start` which would reduce your search space.  Eg:- `pos = lst.index(3,4)` would return position of element with value 3 from the 4th position onwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just traverse list once storing the index values as you go through the list. This would work in `O(n)` time complexity.

```
inputlist = [0, 1, 0, 4, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 12, 9, 32, 31, 19, 44, 3]
maxvalue = -1
answer= []
for index,element in enumerate(inputlist):
    if element > maxvalue:
        maxvalue = element
        answer.append(index)
print(answer)
```

**Note:**
The amortized time complexity of insertion into a list in `O(1)`. The asymptotic  worst-case run time complexity of insertion is `O(n)` and average case is `O(1)`.You can use a dequeue to speed it up slightly. The asymptotic and amortized worst-case run time complexity of insertion into a dequeue is `O(1)`.

you can read more about it here -> [TimeComplexity of python datastructures](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

OUTPUT

```
[0, 1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 14]
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: append complexity of a list is amortized O(1), while that of a deque is just O(1). So using deque instead of list can be a slightly better idea.

Comment: @FatihAkici Edited the answer as per your suggestion